# Dynamic mixins in LESS?

Tags: html, css, sass, less

Is is possible, I can make totally dynamic classes in LESS? For example, I do something like.

```
.padding(@size){
padding: @size;
}
```

Now, I can do something in LESS like .padding(10px), and it will render properly in LESS. But this would be redundant. Can I do something in HTML like

```
<div class="padding5"></div>
```

and it might render to padding: 5px? In the app I am working on, there are around thousand instances where padding or margin is used, so instead of writing a CSS code for each, I can do it dynamically?
If not, is this possible in SASS?

Comment: No and No. *there are around thousand instances where padding or margin is used* and all their values are different? It seems like your approach to CSS is something like "create macros for inline HTML styles" which is basically not what CSS was developed for (they can't prohibit you to use CSS like this but you're on your own with all of this way issues).

Comment: In short, if you're looking for something like above, your own script (converting whatever HTML attributes into styles of interests) will do the trick. CSS preprocessors do not work with HTML at all (just by definition).

Comment: (Obviously it's never a problem to generate 1000 classes like `.padding-1`... `.padding-1000` with just 3 or 4 lines of Less/Sass code but it's always been considered like an awful misuse...) So if you need some constructive insights (instead of "why do you need this cr...weirdness?") specify your actual problem instead of how you think you could solve it (see [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377)).

Comment: Don't add same question twice, update the first